# Solve $uu_x+u_y=-\frac{1}{2}u$ with characteristics

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristics

I'm stuck trying to solve $uu_x+u_y=-\frac{1}{2}u$ satisfying $u(x,2x)=x^2$, this solution also needs to be in some parametrised form with $x(r,s), y(r,s),u(r,s)$.

So far I have this:

$\dfrac{dx}{ds}=u \longrightarrow x(r,s)=us+x_0$

$\dfrac{dy}{ds}=1 \longrightarrow y(r,s)=s+y_0$

$\dfrac{du}{ds}=-\dfrac{1}{2}u \longrightarrow u(r,s)=u_0e^{-s/2}$

If we have that $y(0)=0$ we can see that $y=s$, so we can replace each instance of $s$ with $y$. I know I will end up with an implicit function, but I don't know how to apply the $u(x,2x)=x^2$ condition from here. I was thinking about directly plugging in $u(x,2x)=u_0e^{-x}=x^2\Rightarrow u_0=x^2e^x$ and then after letting $x(0)=r$ (the initial curve) and some substitutions end up with $u=(2uy-x)^2e^{-x}e^{-y/2}$ but I don't think that's correct.

I feel like there's a step missing before I start doing that. I have only just been introduced to PDEs, so all of this is new, any help is welcome and I appreciate your patience with me.

As an aside, I know there is [another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2206494/use-the-method-of-characteristics-to-solve-u-tuu-x-frac12u-0) that is asking the exact same thing that I am, but they introduce some $\Phi$ and $F$ notations which I have never seen before and leaves me more confused than I initially was.

Comment: ${{dx}\over {ds}}=u$ does not mean $x=us+x_0$. Remember that $u$ is a function of $s$; You are treating $u$ in this DE as if it were a constant. You should parameterize the IC to ensure $$\big(x(0,t),y(0,t),z(0,t)\big)=\big(t,2t,t^2\big)$$

Comment: Of course, that makes much more sense. So in my equations should I have $x_0=t,y_0=2t,z_0=t^2$ instead of my $x_0=s$ and $y_0=0$?

Answer (score 1):

$$2uu_x+2u_y=-u$$
Charpit-Lagrange characteristic ODEs :
$$\frac{dx}{2u}=\frac{dy}{2}=\frac{du}{-u}$$
First characteristic from $\frac{dx}{2u}=\frac{du}{-u}$
$$2u+x=c_1$$
Second characteristic from $\frac{dy}{2}=\frac{du}{-u}$
$$u\:e^{y/2}=c_2$$
General solution of the PDE on implicit form $c_2=F(c_1)$ :
$$\boxed{u\:e^{y/2}=F\left(2u+x\right)}$$
$F$ is an arbitrary function (to be determined according to some boundary condition).

Condition : $u(x,2x)=x^2$
$$x^2\:e^{2x/2}=F\left(2x^2+x\right)$$
$X=2x^2+x\quad\implies\quad x=\frac14\left(-1+\sqrt{1+8X} \right)$

The sign minus of the square root is excluded (in puting $X=2x^2+x$ into the square root).
$$F(X)=\frac{1}{16}\left(-1+\sqrt{1+8X} \right)^2 e^{-\frac14\left(-1+\sqrt{1+8X} \right)} $$

We put $F(X)$ into the above general solution where $X=2u+x$ :

$$\boxed{u\:e^{y/2}=\frac{1}{16}\left(-1+\sqrt{1+8(2u+x)} \right)^2 e^{-\frac14\left(-1+\sqrt{1+8(2u+x)} \right)}}$$
This is the solution on the form of implicit equation which satisfies both the PDE and the condition.

Comment: The initial condition is that $u(x,2x)=x^2$, this is one of the problems I was running into, the fact it's a squared term of $x$ and not a linear one made things slightly more difficult

Comment: Also, there seems to be a sign error in the first equation on the $u_y$ term, but I can manage that. I want to ask about $c_1$ and $c_2$, I usually see $u$ represented as a function of $r$ and $s$, where $r$ is the inital curve in the $x$-$u$ plane and $s$ tells us how it progresses into the $y$ direction. Are $c_1$ and $c_2$ directly related to $r$ and $s$ in some way?

Comment: The typo in the PDE is corrected. The boundary condition is updated. If fact the relationship $c_2=F(c_1)$ is a simplified form of $\Phi(c_1,c_2)=0$ with arbitrary fonction $\Phi$ of two variables. In this method it is not taken account of a "direction". No symbol $r,s$ appear. At end, one is supposed to check the final result in puting it into the PDE and to check the consistency with the specified condition. Eventually some unvalid solution might be rejected.

Answer (score 0):

Let us apply the [method of characteristics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics), with initial condition $u(x_0, 2x_0) = x_0^2$:

- $\frac{\text d}{\text d s} y = 1$, letting $y(0) = 2x_0$ we know $y = 2x_0 + s$.
- $\frac{\text d}{\text d s} u = -\frac12 u$, letting $u(0) = x_0^2$ we know $u = x_0^2 e^{-s/2}$
- $\frac{\text d}{\text d s} x = u$, letting $x(0) = x_0$ we know $x = x_0 - 2 x_0^2 (e^{-s/2} - 1)$

The latter is rewritten
$$
x = x_0 - 2 u\, (1 - e^{y/2-x_0}) .
$$
Resolution w.r.t. $x_0$ yields the expression
$$
x_0 = W_n\left(-2u e^{y/2-2 u - x} \right) + 2 u + x
$$
where $W_n$ is the analytic continuation of the product log function, to be substituted in $ue^{y/2} = x_0^2 e^{x_0}$ to get the final implicit expression.

Comment: I've tried to take this a bit further, but again, no real progress. I tried to rearrange and substitute to eliminate $s$ or $x_0$, neither of which worked. I really am quite lost here. I don't think I can find ways to eliminate either of those variables, which means that I'm going to end up with some implicit function where $u(x,y)$ will contain $s$ and $x_0$, or, $u(x,y)=u(x(x_0,s),y(x_0,s))$, I'm just not sure what to do with the information that I have to end up with that kind of answer.

Comment: @Maksymillian5275 analytical resolution might involve special functions, see updated post (I used Wolfram alpha to solve for $x_0$).